# How to exit from async.forEach loop when certain condition occurs + node

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I am working on node js async forEach loop. I want to exit from the async loop when certain condition occurs. I tried with return callback. But it doesn't seems working. How can i solve this? Is it possible to exit from async loop .

```
   async.forEach(usertype.permissions, function (permission, cb) {
      if (usertype.type === 'super_admin') {
       console.log('super admin')
         flag = 1;
         // here i want to exit from the loop
         //return cb();
        }
      if (permission.description === 'Can this use?' && permission.default_value.indexOf('YES') > -1) {
       flag = 1;
       return cb();
       } 
      else {
       if (permission.description === 'Ca?' && permission.default_value.indexOf('YES') > -1) {
        flag = 1;
        console.log('permission to advance')
        return cb();
        } 
      else {
       cb();
            }
           }
         }, function () {
      // The code i want to execute after exit from the loop
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

`async`'s various functions will "exit early" if you pass a value to the callback, typically an `Error`:

```
async.forEach(usertype.permissions, function (permission, cb) {
  if(someCondition) return cb(new Error('I want to exit here'));
}, function(err) {
  // Finished
});
```

However, unless the getters on your `permission` objects are asynchronous, I'm not sure why you're using the async library.